# Author problem with Google scholar

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

I've just published a paper on [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.05013) and then manually added this article to my google scholar [profile](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=xBOX2bIAAAAJ&hl=en). Which is fine, and shows the article in my google scholar profile. But when I search for my paper in the google scholar ([the search link](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=The+effects+of+non-helical+component+of+hypermagnetic+field+on+the+evolution+of+the+matter-antimatter+asymmetry%2C+vorticity%2C+and+hypermagnetic+field&btnG=)) and click on my name (A Rezaei) it shows someone else's profile. Will google automatically fix this or should I do something?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yes. If you check my [profile](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=xBOX2bIAAAAJ&hl=en) you can see the Verified email at mail.sbu.ac.ir at the top.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I think this has been asked several times [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/163647/68109) as well as on [Google support forums](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/58375217?hl=en), but I am yet to see any answer. Looking at related problems with Google Scholar, it seems quite likely to me that there is no fix, unless it happens automatically. (Some past answers suggest contacting Google, but their contact page for Scholar seems to be no longer active.) Please post an update if you find a solution!

Comment: The issue also seems to be that your paper also appears in the other author's profile, so Google may not be sure who the true author is.